# MongoDB: How to Get the Lowest Value Closer to a given Number and Decrement by 1 Another Field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given the following document containing 3 nested documents...

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("56116d8e4a0000c9006b57ac"), "name": "Stock 1", "items" [
    { "price": 1.50, "description": "Item 1", "count": 10 }
    { "price": 1.70, "description": "Item 2", "count": 13 }
    { "price": 1.10, "description": "Item 3", "count": 20 }
  ]
}
```

... I need to select the sub-document with the lowest price closer to a given amount (here below I assume 1.05):

```
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$items"},
  {$sort: {"items.price":1}},
  {$match: {"items.price": {$gte: 1.05}}},
  {$group: {
    _id:0, 
    item: {$first:"$items"}
  }},
  {$project: {
    _id: "$item._id",
    price: "$item.price",
    description: "$item.description"
  }}
]);
```

This works as expected and here is the result:

```
"result" : [
    {
        "price" : 1.10,
        "description" : "Item 3",
        "count" : 20
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

Alongside returning the item with the lowest price closer to a given amount, I need to decrement `count` by 1. For instance, here below is the result I'm looking for:

```
"result" : [
    {
        "price" : 1.10,
        "description" : "Item 3",
        "count" : 19
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether you actually want to "update" the result or simply "return" the result with a decremented value. In the former case you will of course need to go back to the document and "decrement" the value for the returned result.

Also want to note that what you "think" is efficient here is actually not. Doing the "filter" of elements "post sort" or even "post unwind" really makes no difference at all to how the [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator works in terms of performance.

The better approach is to basically "pre filter" the values from the array where possible. This reduces the document size in the aggregation pipeline, and the number of array elements to be processed by `$unwind`:

```js
db.stocks.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "items.price": { "$gte": 1.05 }
  }},
  { "$project": {
      "items": {
        "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": {
                "input": "$items",
                "as": "item",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gte": [ "$$item.price", 1.05 ] }
                    ],
                    "$$item",
                    false
                }
            }},
            [false]
        ]
      }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$items"},
  { "$sort": { "items.price":1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": 0, 
     "item": { "$first": "$items" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$item._id",
    "price": "$item.price",
    "description": "$item.description"
  }}
]);
```

Of course that does require a MongoDB version 2.6 or greater server to have the available operators, and going by your output you may have an earlier version. If that is the case then at least loose the `$match` as it does not do anything of value and would be detremental to performance.

Where a `$match` is useful, is in the document selection before you do anything, as what you always want to avoid is processing documents that do not even possibly meet the conditions you want from within the array or anywhere else. So you should **always** `$match` or use a similar query stage first.

At any rate, if all you wanted was a "projected result" then just use [`$subtract`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) in the output:

```js
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$item._id",
    "price": "$item.price",
    "description": "$item.description",
    "count": { "$subtract": [ "$item.count", 1 ] }
  }}
```

If you wanted however to "update" the result, then you would be iterating the array ( it's still an array even with one result ) to update the matched item and "decrement" the count via [`$inc`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/):

```js
var result = db.stocks.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "items.price": { "$gte": 1.05 }
  }},
  { "$project": {
      "items": {
        "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": {
                "input": "$items",
                "as": "item",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$gte": [ "$$item.price", 1.05 ] }
                    ],
                    "$$item",
                    false
                }
            }},
            [false]
        ]
      }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$items"},
  { "$sort": { "items.price":1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": 0, 
     "item": { "$first": "$items" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": "$item._id",
    "price": "$item.price",
    "description": "$item.description"
  }}
]);

result.forEach(function(item) { 
    db.stocks.update({ "item._id": item._id},{ "$inc": { "item.$.count": -1 }})
})
```

And on a MongoDB 2.4 shell, your same aggregate query applies ( but please make the changes ) however the `result` contains another field called `result` inside it with the array, so add the level:

```js
result.result.forEach(function(item) { 
    db.stocks.update({ "item._id": item._id},{ "$inc": { "item.$.count": -1 }})
})
```

So either just `$project` for display only, or use the returned result to effect an `.update()` on the data as required.